# How to use select2 with remote data if the data items don't provide the "id" and "text" fieldnames?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown, which is configured for using with remote data. However, my remote datasource provides the search results in a format which seems to be not compatible with select2. The remote data is for example like this:

```
...
items: [ { value: 1, displayText: "First" }, { value: 2, displayText: "Second" } ]
...
```

but select2 seems to expect the "id" and "text" fields instead. I've checked all options, and tried to play with `formatSelection`, `formatResult` callbacks, but had no success until now, I always get javascript errors about "item.text" being undefined.

I cannot provide a jsFiddle because the web API is not public unfortunately.

Is there a way to configure select2 for using a custom "id" and "text" field? Or what else could be a good workaround for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out almost immediately after I posted my question. Probably this is not the most efficient way to do this, so I'm still happy if someone has a better answer.

I managed to do a conversion in the `results` callback in the `ajax` options.

```
$("#mySelect").select2({
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      ajax: {
        url: '/',
        params: {
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
        },
        quietMillis: 200,
        data: function(term, page) { // page is the one-based page number tracked by Select2
          return {
            search: term,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageIndex: page-1,
          };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
          var more = (page * 10) < data.Total; // whether or not there are more results available
          return { results: $.map(data.Results, function(e, i) {
            return { id: e.value, text: e.displayText, data: e };
          }), more: more };
        }
      }
```